# gsconfig add WFS with shapefile via Python

Tags: python, geoserver, gsconfig

I am generating a shapefile with a Python script and I want to publish it via GeoServer. The GeoServer is running on localhost 8080.

I learned from [this](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_wfscascade.html) website that the workflow would be:

1. Add a store
2. Specify the data source name
3. Specify the getCapabilities URL
4. Enter password that is the same as the server
5. Publish

So far I have come up with this code, but it is somehow a mess and I do not know what exactly I am doing...

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog
from random import randrange
import geoserver.util

nomen='test{}'.format(randrange(10000))
cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/", "admin", "geoserver")
geosolutions = cat.get_workspace("workspacename")
shapefile_plus_sidecars = geoserver.util.shapefile_and_friends('25832')
ft = cat.create_featurestore(nomen, shapefile_plus_sidecars, workspacename)
that_layer = cat.get_layer(nomen)
print(that_layer.name)
```

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to cascade a remote WFS (that is republish someone else's layers in your own GeoServer). You want to use the [GeoServer REST API to add](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/datastores.yaml) and publish a shapefile.

So you need to look at this [tutorial](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/python_gsconfig.html#working-with-featuretypes-vector-data) from GeoSolutions

Comment: true that! thx!